# Function not resolving to base class overload

Tags: c++, crtp

I tried using CRTP with this (simplified) example:

Base class:

```
template <class Derived>
class Base
{
public: 
    int method(int in, int& out2)
    {
        return derived().method(in, out2);
    }

    int method(int in)
    {
        int dummy;
        return this->predict(in, dummy);
    }

protected:
    Base() {}
private:
    Derived& derived()
    {
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};
```

Derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public: 
    int method(int in, int& out2)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
};
```

The problem is, when I try to use `method(int in)` with an instance of the `Derived` class, like:

```
Derived d;
int res = d.method(5);
```

The compiler (icc in this case, but have also tried with msvc) gives me the following error:

> error #165: too few arguments in function call

It seems that the compiler is not realizing that there exists an overload which only takes one parameter, from the `Base<Derived>` class (from which `Derived` inherits publicly, so I think it should be accesible).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any hints will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of `Derived::method` means that the compiler will not consider overloads of `Base::method` when attempting to bind the call. To fix this, add `using Base::method;` to the derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    using Base::method; 
    int method(int in, int& out2)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
};
```

Comment: So this had nothing to do with templates. Damn, more than 5 years coding in C++ and never went through this. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

When a non-virtual function is defined with the same name as a `Base::method`, it **overshadows** the `Base::method` in the `Derived` class, which is also known as **Name Hiding**.

To prevent this, you have to explicitly mention the name of the method with the class using the `using` operator, i.e. your `Derived` class code should be modified to:

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public: 
    using Base::method; //makes the 'method' declaration of Base class 
                        //visible here as well.
    int method(int in, int& out2)
    {
        // Logic here
    }
};
```